# Runtime error in StringBuilder instance

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Please, help me understand, what's wrong with this code. (I am trying to build a string, taking parts of it line by line from a text file).

I get a runtime error ***"In the instance of the object reference not set to an object"***  on the line `strbuild.Append(str);`

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("buf.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
        strbuild = null;

        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string str = null;
            str = reader.ReadLine().ToString();

            string segment = str.Substring(0, 1);

            if (segment == "A")
            {
                strbuild.Append(str); //here  i get an error
            }
            else if (segment == "B")
            {
                strbuild.Append("BET");
            }

        }
        printstr = strbuild.ToString();
        reader.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(printstr);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
strbuild = null;
```

What do you *expect* to happen when you then call `strbuild.Append(...)`? Why are you setting `strbuild` to null at all?

You seem to be fond of two-line variable initialization - here's another example:

```
string str = null;
str = reader.ReadLine().ToString();
```

This would be more easily readable as just:

```
string str = reader.ReadLine();
```

(`ReadLine` already returns a string, so you don't need to call `ToString()` on the result.)

However, I *do* suggest that you use a `using` statement for the `StreamReader` - otherwise when an exception is thrown, you'll be leaving the reader open.

One nice thing about `TextReader.ReadLine()` is that it returns null when you're done. You don't need to peek and *then* read.

Finally, if you're only testing a single character you don't need a substring - just use the string indexer to get a char. So, you could have:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// Consider using File.OpenText
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("buf.txt", Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string line;
    // Normally side-effect + test is ugly, but this is a common and
    // neat idiom
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // TODO: What do you want to happen for empty lines?
        char segment = str[0];
        if (segment == 'A')
        {
            builder.Append(line);
        }
        else if (segment == 'B')
        {
            builder.Append("BET");
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the stringbuilder to null after initialization.

Change

```
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder(); 
strbuild = null;
```

to

```
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
```

leaving out the line

```
strbuild = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
  StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
  strbuild = null;
```

to

```
  StringBuilder strbuild = null;
  strbuild = new StringBuilder();
```

or, to prevent this kind of error:

```
  StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some many errors within your example, here is a first corrected version:

```
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();

// Put resource into using statements, for deterministic cleanup
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("buf.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string line;

    //Maybe looks a little ugly the first time, but is commonly used to
    //process all the lines of a file (.ReadToEnd() can cause memory problems
    //on really big files)
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Instead of if, else if, else if, etc just take a switch
        //statement. Makes it much easier to read.
        switch (line[0])
        {
            //If you need case insensitivity put both versions of the character
            //before your first line of code
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                strbuild.Append(line);
                break;
            //Otherwise just use the lower or upper case version you like
            case 'B':
                strbuild.Append("BET");
                break;
        }
    }
}

//Put the result of the StringBuilder directly into the Show() function
MessageBox.Show(strbuild.ToString());
```

Comment: While it's nice that you cleaned it up for them, you didn't explain why you made the changes or what was causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Joshua: So added some comments to the code. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: +1 for turning attention to possible using of "switch" statement. Thanks!